# Products.Poi and Subversion integration

Tags: svn, plone

Is there any ready-to-use solution for integrating [Products.Poi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Poi) with a Subversion changelog? If not, which would be the steps to code it?

I'd like to have a note added to the Poi issue tracker whenever a commit to the SVN repository references the issue id in the log message. Something like [what is possible to be done with MantisBT](http://alt-tag.com/blog/archives/2006/11/integrating-mantis-and-subversion/), for instance.

Comment: by coding everything is possible.  what is the question?

Comment: Actually, I was asking to see if someone knows whether there is any solution already coded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably create an after-commit hook in subversion for this.

- Check if the log messages mentions #123 (as example).
- Somehow figure out which issue tracker this would need to be posted to. Let's just say you have only one tracker that corresponds to this subversion repository.
- In that hook do a POST with the required info to the url that you would use when submitting a response to an issue.

EDIT: part of the solution may be the [poi.receivemail](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poi.receivemail) package: let your subversion hook send an email to an address that you have hooked up with poi.receivemail and [smtp2zope](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/smtp2zope).

Comment: @albieback Share your postcommit hook if successful, please ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no existing solution or integration for this.

Maurits' proposal might work if you just figure out which urls to use (check the forms)